# Android. Convert string to enum

Tags: java, android, json, enumeration

I use retrofit an Gson. I get the following response from the server:

```
class Data {
 @SerializedName("color") 
 private String color;
  @SerializedName("name")
  String name;
..... 
}
```

As you can see from the example, the color is a String. However, I don't want to do a string comparison every time in the code. I want to use an enum. Can you please tell me if I can convert the String to an enumeration when receiving a response from the server for further ease of use.

Comment: You can use a Mapper

Comment: **Gson fully supports enums**, so how about you start at step 1 and create a `Color` enum and change the `color` field to be of that enum type?

Comment: But the server does not send me an enum, but a string

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
enum Color {
    RED(1), GREEN(2), BLUE(3), YELLOW(4);
    
    private final int id;
    
    Color (int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Color to String:

```
String string = color.toString();
```

String to Color:

```
Color color = Color.valueOf(string);
```

^^ use this to convert the string back to a color.

If it does not work, the color might have been converted to a string differently. In this case, make the server send color.toString(); instead of color.